# C#: Helper Method Dependency Injection within Constructor

Tags: c#

I have a `IData` interface that handles the SQL data access logic and as well as retrieving data from SQL Server:

```cs
public interface IData
{
  Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsers();
}
```

I have a `Emailer` class that sends an email with the list of Users and currently I am injecting `IData` via the constructor and accessing the `GetUsers()` method within another Method of the `Emailer` class:

```cs
public class Emailer
{
  private readonly IData _data;

  public Emailer(IData data)
  {
    _data = data;
  }

  public async Task Send()
  {
    var users = await _data.GetUser(); // access data here
  }
}
```

In an act to try and refactor this code and apply the Single Responsibility principle, I want to abstract away the `GetUser()` logic into its own seperate class however how can I do this without having to initialise IData in the constructor of the new class to avoid having to pass the IData object as a parameter when newing up the class?

Example:

```cs
public class UserData
{
  private readonly IData _data;

  public UserData(IData data)
  {
    _data = data; // not ideal as I'd have to pass the object from the Emailer class and other classes that call Emailer
  }

  public async Task Fetch()
  {
    var users = await _data.GetUser(); // access data here
  }

  public async Task ManipulateUser(){} // example of future extensibility hence the reason for a seperate class
}
```

Could implementing a factory pattern to solve this problem (if yes, how?) or any other ideas?

TIA

Comment: `IData` is a dependent service used by `Emailer`, so you can't completely avoid passing it into `Emailer`. It is just the matter of direct (e.g. via constructor) or indirect (via other service or factory). Either way, you need to change the constructor of `Emailer` (unless the DI framework you use supports property injection). If you are using `new` to create `Emailer`, you might want to change it to be managed by DI, so you don't worry about how it gets `IData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just abstact bind UserData to an interface, called IUserData and inject that into your Emailer class if needed?

I'm on my mobile right now but if you like I can post a code example later if you don't understand.

--UPDATE--

Here is the updated code.

```
//Refactor your existing classes to look like this.
public interface IData
{
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsers();
}

public interface IEmailer
{
    Task Send();
}

public class Emailer : IEmailer
{
    private readonly IUserData _userData;

    public Emailer(IUserData userData)
    {
        _userData = userData;
    }

    public async Task Send()
    {
        var users = await _userData.Fetch(); // access data here
    }
}
public interface IUserData
{
    Task Fetch();

    Task ManipulateUser();
}

public class UserData : IUserData
{
    private readonly IData _data;

    public UserData(IData data)
    {
        _data = data; 
    }

    public async Task Fetch()
    {
        var users = await _data.GetUser();
    }

    public async Task ManipulateUser() { } 
}

//Example of class calling Emailer
public interface IRandomClass
{
    Task RunSomeCode();
}

public class RandomClass : IRandomClass
{
    private readonly IEmailer _emailer;
    public RandomClass(IEmailer emailer)
    {
        _emailer = emailer;
    }

    public async Task RunSomeCode()
    {
        //Example code
        await _emailer.Send();
    }
}
```

Binding the dependencies (assuming you're using .netcore)

```
        services.AddScoped<IUserData, UserData>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailer, Emailer>();
        services.AddScoped<IRandomClass, RandomClass>();
```

This should give you a good baseline to work from.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes that can work as well although I'd need to also inject ```IUserData``` to my other classes that are calling the ```Emailer``` class. Im trying to avoid all of that duplication - is there another alternative?

Comment: Why? Aren't you fetching `IUserData`, `IData`, `Emailer` etc from a DI container? It's the DI containers job to inject into each constructor only what is required. Your other classes should only need to know about `Emailer`, right?

Comment: Updated the code. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Compare interfaces to black boxes. They do stuff, but you have no idea of ***how*** they do it.

But, if you look at the interface name and have no idea of ***what*** they are doing, you got it wrong.

In this case, `IData` seems like a database god object. Am I correct? Does it handle all your SQL operations? If so, divide it into different interfaces which all have a clear responsibility. "I handle DB access for user objects" = `IUserData`.

Regarding methods, C# is an object-oriented language, and classes (and interfaces) are the primary way of letting objects communicate. You won't get any benefits in this case if you try to inject methods instead.

*Update*

Do not refractor code to remove dependencies. composition makes the code more robust. Instead, use a Inversion Of Control container to create your classes.

Read this article to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thanks for that, how can I implement an IoC container, do you have any suggestions on how I can do this with my existing code?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using .net 6 on a ASP.NET web api project

Comment: Then it should be activated by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You seem to redesign a class prematurely violating the YAGNI principle. If you aren't extending `UserData` right now, there is no need to introduce a further abstraction that does nothing more than the code already did.

When you do have extra responsibilities then you will create the `UserData` object passing `IData` into its constructor. Then you pass the `UserData` instance  into the `Emailer` constructor. You basically switch one object for another.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid passing ```IData``` object in the constructor? Otherwise I will need to implement it in the Emailer class as well as other methods calling the Emailer class which isn't a problem but I thought there might be a cleaner alternative?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If you bind the emailer class to an interface, and Inject the email services in your other classes, and the emailer service injects IUserData, any code making use of the Emailer service would not need to inject IUserData.

Comment: Awesome! Let me know if you need help with this :)

Comment: @GeoffreyFook yes please, when you get a second :)

Answer (score 0):

`IData` seems too generic for this use case. You can instead introduce `IUserData`
which would be only responsible for handling data access for the User.

Then your setup will look like this:

```
public interface IUserData
{
  Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsers();
}

public class UserData: IUserData
{
  public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsers()
  { ... }
}

public interface IEmailer
{
  Task Send();
}

public class Emailer : IEmailer
{
  private readonly IUserData _userData;

  public Emailer(IUserData userData)
  {
    _userData = userData;
  }

  public async Task Send()
  {
    var users = await _userdata.GetUser();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can have 3 layers with a generic `Data` class in charge of all the data access operations and have the `UserData` class fine-grain it. This of course depends on how large and unmanageable can this data service become. I personally prefer to have tailor-made services for each data access use case.